# Provide a guidance in python script

Tags: python

I've written a python code which takes input from the user and manipulates the inputs to provide result.
I want in that to provide a help like function which appears if the user left one of the entry blank.

```
    dir  = raw_input("Enter dir:")
    path = raw_input("Enter path:")

    print random_method(dir, path)
```

Now if the user did not enter any value for dir or path, there must be a warning or a guidance to tell before python raises it's own errors.

Thanks

Comment: If your interface is at all complicated just use the standard library. http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean like this:

```
dir  = raw_input("Enter dir:")
if not dir:
    dir = raw_input("Do you really want to leave a blank? Enter dir:")
path = raw_input("Enter path:")
if not path:
    path = raw_input("Do you really want to leave a blank? Enter dir:")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
dir  = raw_input("Enter dir:")
path = raw_input("Enter path:")
if '' in (dir.strip(),path.strip()): #if anyone of these is empty then print the error
    print "either dir or path is empty"
else: 
    print random_method(dir, path)
```